# Memory allocation failure in excel while loading cube data into excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I have been getting error as below while loading data into excel from ssas cube.

> We could't get data from an external data source.Please try again 
>           later.
>           if the problem persist, please contact the administrator for the 
>           external data source.Here is the error message that was returned from 
>           the analysis server named server\instance
>
> Memory error: Allocation failure: Not enough storage is available to 
>           process this command. If using 32-bit version of the product, consider
>           upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory 
>           available on the machine.

Comment: Seems like a RAM issue. Try closing All the other applications from Task manager and run it again.

Comment: issue with server RAM or my local system RAM

Comment: Your System, where you are loading the Data in Excel.

Comment: Ok let me try again

Comment: is 8GB or 16 RAM not enough for this operation even if we open multiple applications

Comment: I am not sure about that. But the Error seems like to point in that direction only. Try fetching a part of the data instead of complete data.

Comment: present using 32-bit version excel is that a problem

Comment: Can we resolve this issue by updating to 64-bit version excel or enabling windows file page in system

Comment: 32-bit Excel limits you to 2 Gb of memory. It does not matter if you have 8 or 16 Gb. I would simply try it on a machine with 64 bit Excel and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: I’m not positive it’s the client system RAM that’s low. Can you monitor memory on the server to see if it hits TotalMemoryLimit (default of 80% of server RAM) then fails? Also monitor RAM usage in the excel.exe process to see which is the culprit. Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: GregGalloway currently I am using 32-Bit.